# What is the difference between Events & Events Logs?

Tags: c#, .net, event-log, event-viewer

What is the benefit of using the newer `EventLogReader` found in namespace `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader` over the traditional approach of creating and `EventLog` and reading the entries in the usual fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the traditional approach is that you have to load all the entries into memory and then filter them on the client - the [`EventLog.Entries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entries.aspx) collection loads everything in memory.

With the new approach the events will not be loaded on the client. You could [`write queries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671200.aspx) to retrieve only the events you are interested on the client.

So you will be consuming much less memory if you use the new class and your code will probably run faster.

Comment: Is the only benefit efficiency and performance. Is there additional information recoding and retrieved?

Comment: `Is the only benefit efficiency and performance.` - like if that was not enough :-) `Is there additional information recoding and retrieved?` - No.

Comment: I am writing a class library which needs to consider both methods of retrieving event logs hence the weird :) question. Also sometimes Microsoft introduces new features and quirks without writing enough/any documentation. Thanks!